# jQuery.post() data not "posting"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am working on a project that requires posting JSON data to a specific URL. I am trying to use the jQuery.post() method to do this. I have two problems I can't seem to figure out.

The first problem:

```
jQuery.post("http://cowbell.grooveshark.com/more.php?getCommunicationToken", dataString, function(data){ alert(data) } );
```

Using a packet sniffer I discovered that the variable dataString was not being posted. Really no content was being posted at all.

The second problem is that the more.php script was returning the the content below in a packet:

```
could not parse, no method specified!
```

This isn't a problem at the moment; however, the success function in my jQuery.post() alerted with an empty data variable.

Here are my references:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- http://nettech.wikia.com/wiki/Grooveshark_Internal_API

Thanks for any help anyone has!

Comment: Would you post more code, including the the code that sets `dataString`?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do ajax-requests to other domains due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), quote from the jQuery API page you linked:

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol.

Comment: Nope, POST/GET doesn't matter. It's the same security issue. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Does the domain you are posting to have a web service that it can expose to you? That will help you in posting the data correctly...